# Using AMD R9 M375?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

Recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my Lenovo Ideapad Y700, which has both integrated Intel HD Graphics and a dedicated AMD R9 M375. Under system details it only lists the Intel graphics, however, when I run `lshw -c video` I get this result:

```
  *-display                 
   description: Display controller
   product: Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 81
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:128 memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:a1000000-a103ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a1040000-a105ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:127 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

what exactly does that mean? how do I switch between the two gpus?